# How to count items in a conditional loop using enumerate? Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, enumerate

I have list of lists `a` containing 7 lists, and a list of lists `x` containing 2 lists. I want to test the lists in `a` against those in `x`.

My goal is to make an item-by-item comparison and find out for how many lists in `a` all values are larger than the corresponding item in `x`.

A condition and a counter check whether the a's touch the x's. Note: I am not interested in counting *how many* items in with a list, a1 for example, touch x1. Once a1 and x1 touch, I count that and can move on to a2, and so on.

However, the counter does not properly update. Any suggestions on how to solve this? Here is my code. The results I expect are shown below the code.

**EDIT**

To clarify the expected result, I have updated the example by adding a second value to `x`. So have updated from `x = [[10], [14]]` to `x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]`

This is updated below.

```
x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

def touch(e, f):
    e = np.array(e)
    f = np.array(f)
    count = []
    counter = 0
    for i, lst in enumerate(e):
        if np.all(f > lst): # This is the condition
            counter += 0 # Counts violations of the condition
            count.append(counter)
            if i == 1:
                counter = 0
        else:
            counter += 1 # Counts violations of the condition
            print(counter)
            count.append(counter)
            if i == 1:
                counter = 0
    return count

touching = touch(x, a)
print(touching)
```

The result I expect is this:

```
[2, 6]
```

But I get this:

```
[1, 2]
```

**EDIT**

To clarify the expected result `[2, 6]`: I am comparing for every list in `a` and `x`, item 1 in `a` to item 1 in `x`, item 2 in a to item 2 in `x`.

So: a1_1 (9) (i.e. item 1 in list 1 of `a`) is lower than x1_1 (10). a1_2 (10) is equal to x1_2 (10) - so that means there are 2 violations of the condition. a3_1 (11) > x1_1 (10) and a3_2 (12) > x1_2 (11) and the other lists in a are also higher than their corresponding elements. For x2 (2nd list in x):, all lists in `a` are lower except a7, in which a7_1 (15) is higher than x2_1 and a7_2 is higher than x2_2. Hence `[2, 6]`.

Comment: why would the result be `[2, 6]`?

Comment: Can you please explain how you derive your expected result from your input data?

Comment: Shouldn't be [5,1] the result?

Comment: I expect ```[2, 6]``` because no element in the lists in ```a``` can be lower than or equal to the element in ```x```. Only the last list in ```a``` meets that condition when compared to ```x2```.

Comment: Then the sentence "find out for how many lists in `a` all values are larger than the corresponding item in `x`" should be corrected.

Comment: Please explain, you may be right. But "find out for how many lists in a all values are larger than the corresponding item in x" can be tested by counting how many a's violate np.all(f > lst). Right?

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite follow your reasoning in your code, but you can check a against x in a single list comprehension:

```
x = [[10], [14]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

def touch(x, a):
    return [[ all([asel > xel[0] for asel in ael]) for ael in a].count(False) for xel in x]
touching = touch(x, a)
print(touching)

>>> [2,6]
```

Depending on what you really need, you can change the `>` condition to `>=` or count either **False** or **True** values. If the inner lists of x contain multiple element instead of one given in the example, you need to loop the inner lists as well:

```
x = [[10, 11], [14, 12]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

def touch(x, a):
    return [[all([asel > xsubel for xsubel in xel for asel in ael]) for ael in a].count(False) for xel in x ]
touching = touch(x, a)
print(touching)
```

Comment: What if the lists in ```x``` would also have multiple elements? For example if ```x = [[10, 12], [14, 13]]```.

Comment: Then you would have to loop the inner lists in x as well. See updated answer.

Comment: Great! What I don't understand is that when you add one more list to ```a```, say ``` [17, 18]```, the counter remains the same. While I would expect it to be updated.

Comment: Of course it is the same: you're adding one more list that counts as True. Try adding [7,8] instead, or try counting True instead of False.

Comment: Yes, of course - you are right. My mistake. Thanks a lot. What an amazing list comprehension. I did not know they could be this complex. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are list comprehensions computationally expensive? When extending the list in ```x``` and ```a``` to hundreds of items and adding thousands of lists, the calculations still work but become slow. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: On the contrary: most often they are more efficient. You can find multiple discussions on this site. But if you want to create a list using (nested) for-loops, list-comprehensions are often a better alternative.

Comment: I checked again, but the result I expect is [2, 6]. I am comparing for every list in ```a``` and ```x```, item 1 in ```a``` to item 1 in ```x```, item 2 in ```a``` to item 2 in ```x```. So: a1_1 (9) (item 1 in list 1 of a) is lower than x1_1 (10). a1_2 (10), is equal to x1_2 (10) - so that is two violations of the condition. a3_1 (11) > x1_1 (10) and a3_2 (12) > x1_2 (11) and the other lists in a are also higher than their corresponding elements. For x2 (2nd list in x):, all lists in a are lower except a7, in which a7_1 (15) is higher than x2_1 and a7_2 is higher than x2_2. Hence [2, 6].

Comment: Like I said, you can change counting False's to counting True's in the list comprehension. With your original list, this yields [5,1]: first element in a = False, second element in a = False (10 is not larger than 10), and the other 5 elements are True.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Numpy to avoid any for loops. In the code below I assumed that the list `x` was 1-D by the way, since it seems the sublists it contains consist of 1 element.

```
import numpy as np
x = [10,14]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

e = np.array(x)
f = np.array(a)
touching = (np.sum(np.any(f[...,np.newaxis] <= e, axis = 1), axis = 0))
 
print(touching)
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a different perspective. In python, you can see that:

```
>>> [1, 1] > [1, 2]
False
>>> [1, 1] > [1, 1]
False
>>> [1, 1] > [1, 0]
True
>>> [2, 3] > [3, 3]
False
>>> [2, 3] < [3, 3]
True
>>> [2, 2] > [0, 2]
True
```

So, we can compare entire lists. First flatten the `x` and, then compare `x` with element in `a`

```
x = [[10], [14]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

def touch(e, f):
    e = [q for p in e for q in p] # [10, 14]
    return sum([1 for sub_list in f if sub_list > e])

print(touch(x, a))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple solution without any need for `numpy`

```
x = [[10], [14]]
a = [[9, 10], [10, 11], [11, 12], [12, 13], [13, 14], [14, 15], [15, 16]]

def touch(e, f):
    # We can keep only maximum element of each list
    e = [max(lst) for lst in e]
    count = [0]*len(e)
    for lst in f:
        # Even the minimum must be greater
        min_value = min(lst)
        for i in range(len(e)):
            if min_value>e[i]:
                count[i] += 1
    return count

touching = touch(x, a)
print(touching)
# [5, 1]
```

Comment: There is so much complexity in it though and it do not seems pythonic